# Why body of POST requests to Grizzly HTTP server is incomplete?

Tags: java, http, post, grizzly

I'm using Grizzly HTTP server (grizzly-comet-server-2.2.1.jar). HTTP requests are processed by descendant of `org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler`. Sometimes (it seems to be random) the method `service(Request request, Response response)` is called with `request` parameter for which value of content length header differs from real length of received POST body:

```
request.getInputStream().available() < request.getContentLength().
```

Client is Google Chrome on localhost, Windows 7 SP1. In google chrome development tools Network tab I can see that body of request was sent fully. So I think cause of problem is server.

It happens both for big requests (40Kb) either for small (150b).

I tried waiting (thread `sleep`) for small time inside service method and for big amount of time too, it didn't help. I tried different settings for HTTP server (for example, IO strategy) with no success too.

Why a request is broken and how can I fix that?

Code for starting server:

```
private HttpServer startServer() {
    final HttpServer server = new HttpServer();
    final NetworkListener listener = new NetworkListener("grizzly", "localhost", new PortRange(57777));

    server.addListener(listener);
    listener.setMaxPendingBytes(1);
    listener.getFileCache().setEnabled(false);
    listener.setChunkingEnabled(true);        
    listener.registerAddOn(new CometAddOn());

    final Transport transport = listener.getTransport();
    transport.setReadBufferSize(100000);

    final MyHttpHandler httpHandler = new MyHttpHandler();
    server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(httpHandler, "/");

    try {
        server.start();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return server;
}
```

Handler itself

```
public class MyHttpHandler extends HttpHandler {

    protected static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyHttpHandler.class);

    public void service(Request
            request, Response
            response) throws Exception {

         if (request.getInputStream().available() != request.getContentLength()) {
             log.error("broken content section: only " + request.getInputStream().available() + " of " +
                    request.getContentLength() + "bytes.");
         }
        response.setContentLength(0);
        response.getWriter().write("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Grizzly server is OK. See answer here http://java.net/jira/browse/GRIZZLY-1235